# Automate (EV) code signing with Certum Certificate

Tags: certificate, code-signing, safenet

I just switched from a DigiCert EV Code Signing Token (that was using the Safenet Client), to a Certum certificate.
Everything was automated (for the Digicert Token) with the help of this little tool https://www.nuget.org/packages/SafenetSign/

The new EV Code Signing token from Certum uses their own Signing Client (called proCertum CardManager). The client does not offer a lot of information about the token, especially the private key container name value.

In order to automate the process for the new Certum token I would need this value, which I can't find anywhere.
[Requirements for automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKzbZ.png)

I am not sure if this private key container name is available only for the SafeNet tokens or not.
This is the Certum Token: https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/141/acr101i-simicro-ccid/

I went through this https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/retrieve-cng-key-container-name-and-unique-name.aspx
Thinking that it might help, but the unique container name's value is equal to the key container's value. And it does not work with the safenetsign automation tool.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUJFe.png)

Don't really know how to continue from here.
Is there any way I could bypass this value for the automation process? Or, is there any other tool I could use for this purpose?